# Python - TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'ESCs' (Class) and 'float'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am working on a program on Raspberry Pi 3 for an autonomous drone, and I have bumped into a strange problem. I'm a bit of a noob, so bear with me. Here is my code so far:

```html
class P_2(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.init = True
    
    def computation(self, phi_de, theta_de, psi_de):
        self.phi_de = phi_de
        self.theta_de = phi_de           
        self.psi_de = phi_de
        phi = phi_de*math.pi/180
        theta = theta_de*math.pi/180
        psi = psi_de*math.pi/180
            
        #some more math stuff
        

class ESCs(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.init = True
          
def motors(self):
        if self.init:
            self.init = False
            phi_d, theta_d, psi_d = raw_input('Enter the desired 
            roll, pitch, and yaw in degrees: ').split()
            phi_d,theta_d,psi_d=[float(phi_d),
            float(theta_d),float(psi_d)]
            oop = P_2()
            oop.computation(self, phi_d, theta_d, psi_d)
            return 0

        else:
            ich = P_2()
            g = ich.computation(self, phi_d, theta_d, psi_d)
            for j in range(len(ich)):
                g[j] *= 180/math.pi

#some more math stuff

while True:
    begin = ESCs()
    begin.motors()
```

I'm running my code on a Raspberry Pi Jessie-Lite image if that helps. After I run my code in the terminal, it keeps throwing an error shown below:

```html
Enter the desired roll, pitch, and yaw in degrees: 0 0 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Quadcopter_main.py", line 10, in <module>
   begin.motors()
  File "Quadcopter_main.py", line 28, in motors
   oop.computation(self, phi_d, theta_d, psi_d)
  File "Quadcopter_main.py", line 41, in computation
   phi = phi_de*math.pi/180
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'ESCs' and 'float'
```

I know that the TypeError: unsupported operand type refers to an error of trying to concatenate two types of different variables (e.g. string and an int), but I am kinda thrown off by getting this type of error by using a class, and I am not sure where the problem could lie in.

Comment: *"trying to concatenate two types of different variables"* - no, you're trying to **multiply** different types. What *should* `phi_de * math.pi / 180` do? You don't define the appropriate magic methods - see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types

Comment: Remove the `self` in `oop.computation(self, phi_d, theta_d, psi_d)` and `g = ich.computation(self, phi_d, theta_d, psi_d)`. Pretty sure this code doesn't even run, but that's probably what the mistake is.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you both for that! I already followed Rawing's suggestion and the error seemed to go away, despite the fact that now there are different errors (lol). I will try to add some magic variables tonight and see if everything goes properly. Rawing, may I ask what gives you the impression that the code doesn't run?

Comment: Well, the `computation` method takes 3 parameters (not counting `self`), but you're giving it 4.

Comment: Thank you Rawing, Guess I have some learning to do!

Comment: @Rawing consider converting the helpful comment into an answer so others can discover the solution